# Firebase Storage uploaded Videos to recycler view in Android

Tags: android, firebase, video-streaming, firebase-storage

I Had uploaded Video Files Directly to Firebase Storage via Console.

I need to get the Videos list in APP and to be played in APP.

Please advise.

Comment: Is this a question? are you asking if you can read data from Firebase Storage and play it in APP? What does that mean?

Comment: Hi Jay, I want to retrieve videos uploaded to Firebase database in my app.

Comment: The Firebase Guide covers the process for [Downloading Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files)